# React/Express APP : Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError. status code === 404

Tags: reactjs, express, components

I am building an app that requires a user to sign in and be authenticated. I have the proper exports and files linked together but I keep getting bounce the same error when I try and sign in a user from the seed file in the database. I have a route defined in my api.js file for login, I have a proper login form as a component and I have a login route defined in my server.js file.

Anytime I try to sign in I get this error "Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST'"

this is my API.js

```
    /** Get token for login from username, password. */
    static async login(data) {
        const { username, password } = data;

        const res = await axios.post(`login`, { username, password });

        if (res.status === 200) {
            const token = jwt.sign({ username }, secret, { expiresIn: '1h' });
            this.token = token;
            return token;
        } else {
            throw new Error(res.data.error.message);
        }
    };
```

LoginForm.js

```
const LoginForm = () => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [token, setToken] = useState(null);

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const data = {
            username,
            password,
        };

        const res = await LearnGuruApi.login(data);

        if (res.status === 200) {
            setToken(res.data.token);
        } else {
            console.log(token);
            console.log(res.data.error.message);
        }
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input
                type="text"
                name="username"
                placeholder="Username"
                value={username}
                onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
            />
            <input
                type="password"
                name="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    );
};
```

Login route from server.js

```
// to login 
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;

    // Check if the username and password are valid.

    if (!username || !password) {
        res.status(401).send('Invalid username or password.');
        return;
    }

    // Generate a token for the user.

    const token = jwt.sign({ username }, secret, { expiresIn: '1h' });

    // Return the token to the user.

    res.status(200).send({ token });
});
```

RE: This is the HTTP Request once I click login for a seed database user.

[HTTP REQUEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuVcD.png)

I tried to alter the code and I even tried to rewrite the code with what I think it should be.

RE: I had a .env file that was overriding the port for the backend server. I now have my front end on 3000 and backend on 3001. However, I feel that they still aren't communicating to eachother

Comment: Are express and react on the same url? Do you have a proxy or do you serve react from express?

Comment: My backend express is on localhost:3001 and the frontend React is localhost:3001. I am not on a proxy.

Comment: Can you provide the HTTP request URL from the browser developer tools - Network tab?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added the screen shot of the HTTP request I looked  liked the Login request was on localhost 3001 and the referer was localhost:3000. I have seen that concurrently could work but that would be me reworking the entire code base.